# Pinging VM guest from host results in destination host unreachable

Tags: networking, virtual-machine

I have a VM with XP, When I ping it from the host I get destination host unreachable.

The network connection is bridged.

What I **can** do:

1. I can ping the router IP from the guest.
2. Internet is working on the guest VM.
3. I can see the VM IP in the connected devices in the router configuration.

What I **can't** do:

1. I can't ping the guest IP from any other machine on the network including the host machine (Getting destination host unreachable).
2. I run arp -a from the host machine I see all devices IP except the VM.
3. I run arp -a from the guest machine I see only the router IP.

Note: The host machine is connected through wireless.

Comment: What host OS? What hypervisor are you running?

Comment: @Zoredache Host = windows 8 enterprise (not 8.1) and using vmware workstation 12